# why in react classes don’t minify very well and they make hot reloading flaky and unreliable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-class-based-component

I'm a beginner learning `react js` and I ask a lot of questions even if it looks simple.

In the [Introduction of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) section, It is mentioned

- It’s hard to reuse stateful logic between components
- Complex components become hard to understand
- Classes confuse both people and machines

I don't know why they hate classes so much, inside which they have mentioned
**`classes don’t minify very well, and they make hot reloading flaky and unreliable`**

And on Google, I found it's hard to understand `how classes don’t minify very well`

can anyone kindly answer this with an example

Comment: 1) Class components are going to be way more verbose than their function counterparts. 2) The overwhelming volume of React questions regarding the misunderstanding of `this` in class components is excellent proof that people are confused by classes. 3) You cannot reuse functions that modify state in class components like you can reuse hooks.

Comment: *I don't know why they hate classes so much* - I don't know that its fair to say the "hate" classes. Classes extend far past just React components. It's just that function components have several advantages over classes when used as React components.

Comment: @BrianThompson very useful information & it would be great if provide an example for `cannot reuse functions that modify state`

Comment: `cannot reuse functions that modify state` this is because by nature, those functions are members of the class they were defined in. You cannot export them from the class to be re-usable in other components. Thats the point of custom hooks. Re-usable behavior.

Comment: @Benjamin very easy explanation! If I'm not wrong you are talking about `this`. But still, I'm not able to understand `why classes don’t minify very well`. first of all, I'm not getting what is `minifying of the class`.

Comment: [minification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/minification) is basically just making your code footprint smaller so that it requires fewer resources with the trade-off of not being very human readable anymore.

Comment: @BrianThompson It's exactly the same as expected, Now, the question is How is different for functional components. I mean why minification of only class components causes flaky hot reloading?

Comment: I think those are separate points. Minification is typically only done during production builds, whereas hot reloading is only done in development. So they probably mean those as separate drawbacks. As far as why, I don't know, maybe someone else knows

Comment: This is a relatively old question but to answer your question about hot reloading, when hot reloading a component, that component should be re-created. If you are using a class component, the whole class should be re-created so it looses it's state because the state of the component is stored in the class itself. But state is not lost in function components because state is not stored in the function body directly. (This is  not limited to just state.)